# Laravel Entrust, how to attach existing permission to role

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code I am using, it runs fine but when I'm inside the database checking if everything went okay I get this result

> [image]

Why am I getting 0 for the permission ID and Role ID?

```
$developer = new Role();
$developer->name = 'Test';

$view_customers = new Permission();
$view_customers->name = 'view_customers';
$view_customers->display_name = 'View Customers';

$developer->attachPermission($view_customers->id);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$developer = Role::where('name','=','Test')->get->first();

//if you want to attach new permission
$view_customers = new Permission();
$view_customers->name = 'view_customers';
$view_customers->display_name = 'View Customers';

//if you want to attach existing permission ex. you already have 'view_customers' in permission table 
$view_customers = Permission::where('name','=','view_customers')->get->first();

$developer->attachPermission($view_customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`attachPermission()` works by model or array, if you want atach or detach by id use this

```
$developer->perms()->attach($view_customers->id);
```